# Dealing with word documents on svn branches - How to merge or avoid merging

Tags: svn, ms-word

Our project has a structure like this:

```
Project
    src
        ...
    Documentation
        documentA.doc
        documentB.doc
    ...
```

The svn tree looks like this:

```
Project
    BRANCHES
        New Feature Branch 1
            src
                ...
            Documentation
                documentA.doc
                documentB.doc
            ... 
        New Feature Branch 2
            src
                ...
            Documentation
                documentA.doc
                documentB.doc
            ... 
    TRUNK
        Project
            src
                ...
            Documentation
                documentA.doc
                documentB.doc
            ...
```

Working on features on a branch works great.  Code is just text so merging is ok.

Merging word files does not work.

Is there a way to enforce that .doc files or the `Documentation` folder is NOT edited on the branch?  Ideally what I would prefer to do is just use latex (easy merges, plus you don't have to deal with word) but my organization would not switch to latex.  What are the best practices for dealing with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as an idea: would it be possible to only branch the source-path for feature branches (if your other folder structure allows that)? That way at least you would not have the doc's in the branch...

Further: I have also tried to source-control word documents as .rtf's (because that's not a binary format) - doesnt work either. Word just writes too much stuff into those files...

Comment: I think that what I would like to do is use something like latex.  That would make merges easer.

Comment: I think about using markup (wiki-markup). My only problem now is that it requires clients to have a markup viewer...